# Sending events between 2 custom elements with shadow DOM

Tags: javascript, shadow-dom, custom-element

I have 2 Custom Elements with shadow DOMs. One is a button that dispatches a custom event and one is a dialog that listens for that event. The event is not received.

```
//button.ts
export class ModalButton extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
  super();
  let _shadowRoot = this.attachShadow({ mode: 'open' });
  let button = document.createElement('button');
  _shadowRoot.appendChild(button);
  button.addEventListener('click', () => {
    button.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('modal-open', {
      bubbles: true,
      composed: true
    }));
  });
 }
}

//modal.ts
export class ModalDialog extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
    let _shadowRoot = this.attachShadow({ mode: 'open' });
    let dialog = <HTMLDialogElement>document.createElement('dialog');
    _shadowRoot.appendChild(dialog);
    _shadowRoot.addEventListener('modal-open', () => {
      dialog.showModal();
    });
  }
}

// index.ts
import { ModalButton } from './button';
import { ModalDialog } from './modal';

customElements.define('ce-modal', ModalDialog);
customElements.define('ce-button', ModalButton);
```

**Fixed it**: The error was in the HTML markup where `<ce-button>` and `<ce-modal>` were siblings. The event was (of course!) not able to bubble/propagate to the modal...
I am now appending `ce-button` in the shadow dom of `ce-modal` and only use `<ce-modal>` in the HTML markup.